# Создание SOAP сервиса на основе wsdl

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

У меня есть файла `wsdl` [яндекс спеллера](https://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice?WSDL) как мне поднять свой soap сервис на основе этой wsdl?

через какую библиотеку? пытался через `spyne`, но не нашел как именно создать на основе моей `wsdl` там только создание отдельно своего `Soap` сервиса.

Comment: Почему именно wsdl, а не json-api? Вам так важна скорость?

Comment: wsdl, насколько знаю, это мелкомягких история, поэтому всё то, что не виндовое (не C#, F#) интегрируется с натягом. По крайней мере, на го было неприятно это делать.

Comment: @hedgehogues мне не важна скорость у меня просто есть желание поднять `SOAP` сервис на питоне то что его можно поднять на `C#` и `Java` я знаю, мне просто интересно насколько возможно это реализовать на питоне

Comment: Возможно, но для чего использовать инструмент не по назначению? Это примерно также, как дрель использовать вместо молотка. Кроме того, я почти не сомневаюсь, что все поделия, которые Вы будете для этого использовать, окажутся бажеными. Конюшен Вы поразгребаете. ИМХО, для питона есть протобуф, который яндекс почему-то не предоставляет. В противном случае стоит пользоваться JSON-API. Извините за нравоучения.

Comment: @hedgehogues понял спасибо, Ничего страшного =)

Comment: Вопрос, вероятно должен звучать: "как мне написать клиент к SOAP-сервису при наличии wsdl"? Если так, то: a)suds - у меня был позитивный опыт, но это было года три назад, b) видел использование `zeep` - вроде ОК

Comment: На основе wsdl генерируется _клиент_, а не _сервис_. Сперва пишется сервис (вручную или на основе фреймворка/библиотеки), потом генерируется wsdl (описание сервиса), а уже с его помощью генерируется код клиента.

Comment: wsdl это вовсе не поделие мелкомягких, это международный стандарт. К сожалению, только microsoft сделали хорошую его поддержку в своих продуктах. Другие _не осилили_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагая:

1. Имеется в виду создание клиента к SOAP-сервису имея wsdl-файл
2. python - python 3.x

Я рекомендую следующие варианты:

1. [Suds](https://github.com/cackharot/suds-py3)
2. [Zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master)

С suds у меня у самого позитивный опыт, но опыт 3-летней давности, zeep - по опыту коллег.

И та и другая библиотека при инициализации клиента позволяет использовать в качестве `url`-а для wsdl - файловые ссылки.

Comment: Wow! That was totally unexpected ! .. argh хм. Тут же по-русски говорим? Это был мой первый опыт здесь )